# How to Discover Function Relating Two Variables

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, correlation

I have two variables, call them $x$ and $y$, that can possess any arbitrary positive integer value. I have an automated process that produces an output based on these variables. I do not, however, know precisely how that output is being derived.

I can execute this process an arbitrary number of times and record the results, forming a table of $x$ and $y$ values with their resulting outputs. What I lack is a method for using such a table to obtain the performed function. Does such a thing exist? It has been a long time since I've dealt with math of this abstract nature and much of my vocabulary for dealing with it is rusty in the extreme.

I've noted some cyclicity in the nature of the results (the output is 4 when x and y are both $2^n+1$ for an arbitrary number $n$, frex) but am struggling with generalizing that and other observed cyclicities into a general function that encompasses all possible $x,y$ values.

Comment: In general this is hard. However if you want an approximation to this function, there are many methods to do this.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the data points?

Comment: Not at all, but I'm not sure what the best manner of doing so would be. I have rather a large number of points at this date. Here's a few of the other patterns I've observed:

2^n+1 by 2^(n+1)+1 = 5;

2^n+1 by 2^(n-1)+2^(n-2)+1 = 9;

2^n+1 by 2^n+2^(n+1)+1 = 6;

Comment: Interestingly, 2^n+2^(n+1)+1 by 2^n+2^(n+1)+1 also always equals 9.

Comment: Linked are the x,y and result for 3-128 and 3-256 (run separately due to speed, 3-128 are not repeated within the 3-256 set). Also, the function appears to be commutative so x,y can be input as y,x without issue.

Comment: 3-128: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_A39_mwXavoQTFLRUhwVk9TcUk/view?usp=sharing

3-256: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_A39_mwXavoU19qSkRXZkJhWXM/view?usp=sharing